# Login SSH with .ppk file on Ubuntu Terminal

Tags: server, ssh, login, remote-login

I have a production server. To login to the server I must use a `.ppk` file.

How to login with Ubuntu Terminal and `.ppk` file?

I tried this :

```
ssh -i location/file.ppk username@server-ip
```

but it is showing an error message.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Unable to connect to remote server via SSH (requires public key)](http://askubuntu.com/questions/25277/unable-to-connect-to-remote-server-via-ssh-requires-public-key)

Answer (score 131):

If you only have .ppk file then it would be useful to create a .pem file and then connect to your server using that.

In you Ubuntu computer, install `putty-tools` with the following command:

```
sudo apt-get install putty-tools
```

Now convert your `.ppk` file to `.pem` using the following command:

```
puttygen yourkey.ppk -O private-openssh -o yourkey.pem
```

Set the proper permission to use the `.pem` file with following command:

```
chmod 400 yourkey.pem
```

Now connect to your server using the below command:

```
ssh -i yourkey.pem serverusername@server-ip
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Highest answer to mention .pem and permissions.

Comment: for me, @finn answer can't solve, but this could solve my problem, thanks.

Comment: This should be higher vote and accepted answer

Comment: This answer shows that a little extra details and well written/formated answer is way more helpful than a plain syntax or documentation link

Comment: Thanks it's working for me.

Answer (score 75):

You can convert a `.ppk` file in ubuntu with installing `putty-tools`. So

```
apt-get install putty-tools
```

Then youn can convert the `.ppk` file with `puttygen` to OpenSSH's format like so:

```
puttygen <the_key.ppk> -O private-openssh -o <new_openssh_key>.key
```

Comment: If you found this solution as a Mac user, you won't find any _putty-tools_. Simply do `brew install putty` and you will have `puttygen`, eventually.

Answer (score 25):

`.ppk` is a file format used by Windows program PuTTYgen.

You can try the following procedure [published by Kaleb Pederson](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2224204/2947502) on StackOverflow:

> `puttygen` supports exporting your private key to an OpenSSH
>   compatible format.  You can then use OpenSSH tools to recreate the public key.
>
> 1. Open PuttyGen
> 2. Click Load
> 3. Load your private key
> 4. Go to `Conversions->Export OpenSSH` and export your private key
> 5. Copy your private key to `~/.ssh/id_dsa` (or `id_rsa`).
> 6. Create the RFC 4716 version of the public key using `ssh-keygen`
>
>    ```
>    ssh-keygen -e -f ~/.ssh/id_dsa > ~/.ssh/id_dsa_com.pub
>    ```
> 7. Convert the RFC 4716 version of the public key to the OpenSSH format:
>
>    ```
>    ssh-keygen -i -f ~/.ssh/id_dsa_com.pub > ~/.ssh/id_dsa.pub
>    ```

Comment: You can do this "off system" if you cannot get putty-tools.

Comment: uudecode failed when trying to convert ssh-keygen -i -f ~/.ssh/id_dsa_com.pub > ~/.ssh/id_dsa.pub

Answer (score 14):

Install the putty tools, if you don`t have on Linux:

```
sudo apt-get install putty-tools
```

Generate the pem file run the following command:

```
puttygen keyname.ppk -O private-openssh -o keyname.pem
```

Place the `pemkey.pem` file in your `~/.ssh` directory:

```
cp keyname.pem ~/.ssh
```

Set the pem file to have the proper permissions:

```
chmod 400 keyname.pem
```

Thats it.