# sftp -i parameter not being recognized (for private key file name)

Tags: sftp

In Ubuntu 20.04, I type `sftp` at the command line, and I see there is a `-i` parameter.

When I try it

```
sftp user@site.com -i Key.ppk
```

it acts like maybe the command is not recognized and gives me the syntax, as though I had typed `sftp -h`.

I have tried keyfiles of both .ppk format, and .pem format.  The key is the current directory, and I tried with and without ./ in front of the filename.  Even if the key was bad, wouldn't it give some useful error message?  I have also tried `-i=keyfile`, but I don't think that's the proper syntax (it continues to prompt for a password in that case, as though ignoring the -i parameter.

I was able to connect with a different user (to same server) that had password only authentication.

[image]

Referencing this [similar question](https://serverfault.com/questions/273967/how-to-use-openssh-sftp-command-with-a-rsa-dsa-key-specified-from-the-command-li/273984):

Answer (score 1):

Per the help message, order matters, the `-i` flag comes before the `destination` so it should be

`sftp -i key user@domain.tld`

Answer (score 0):

Apparently the -i must come before the user@server.

```
sftp -i Key.ppk user@site.com
```

Now I'm getting a different error, but at least I can move forward with debugging.

Comment: AFAIK putty's PPK format is incompatible with OpenSSH. See for example [Login SSH with .ppk file on Ubuntu Terminal](https://askubuntu.com/questions/818929/login-ssh-with-ppk-file-on-ubuntu-terminal)